# How to get a specific network header from selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get a specific header from this web https://alfagift.id/ where in the network you can see that the fingerprint is created on the client side.
[image]

I tried this, however I can't get the categories item where the fingerprint value is located in. Can somebody help?

Currently my code is

```
# install chromium, its driver, and selenium
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
!pip install selenium
# set options to be headless, ..
from selenium import webdriver
from seleniumwire import webdriver  # Import from seleniumwire
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.set_capability(
                        "goog:loggingPrefs", {"performance": "ALL", "browser": "ALL"}
                    )
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
# open it, go to a website, and get results
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)

driver.get('https://alfagift.id/')

log_entries = driver.get_log("performance")
```

I try finding it in the log_entries however it's not there. I've found a java version of fingerprint sniffer https://gist.github.com/clouedoc/4a30d8e279cb486b50bdc27d65dc67bf
however can't apply the same logic for in python.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the requests made in the browser and their headers. Therefore, you can search for the fingerprint header.

```
fingerprintFound = False
for request in driver.requests:
    hdict = dict(request.headers)
    for header_key in hdict.keys():
        if header_key == "fingerprint":
            fingerprint = hdict[header_key]
            fingerprintFound = True
            break
    if fingerprintFound:
        break
print(fingerprint)
```